# Inject own Logic into existing Quakus Extension

Tags: java, quarkus, code-injection, open-telemetry, quarkus-extension

I want to add my Logic into a class (VertexTracesDelegator) of the Open Telemetry Quarkus Extension to get a Callback Method that executes some code.

Because I want to intercept the start and end of traces to measure the used cpu time for example.

Is it even possible to Inject Code into a part that you can't access?

I'm new to Quarkus but I believe something like Interceptors or things where you need to change something in the Code isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this Problem by implementing my own SpanProcessor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).